# Make a dynamic/mask variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this base structure:

```
<div class="level level1">
  <div class="btn foo"></div>
  <div class="btn bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="level level2 foo-wrapper">
  <div class="btn foo-lma"></div>
  <div class="btn foo-orb"></div>
</div>

<div class="level level3 foo-lma-wrapper">
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can do this by declaring some type of variable with a mask:

If I click on `.foo` -> `.foo-wrapper` is shown.

If I then click on `.foo-lma` -> `.foo-lma-wrapper` is shown?

Something like:

```
var goDeeper;

$('.btn').click(function() {

  if ( $(this).hasClass(goDeeper) ) {
    $('.level.'+goDeeper+'-wrapper').fadeIn();
  }

});
```

I guess I have to find the other class of .btn somehow and use it as a variable, but I can't really manage to find a way to do it properly. I've managed to do it with an array, but it really doesn't work on a bigger scale, as I have to insert every `.btn` in the variable - https://jsfiddle.net/pumfya9r/10/

I feel like I'm close, so a little help will be appreciated.

Comment: Will your button only be having `.btn .foo` these two classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks simple enough - on click, select the second class name in the class list, and then display the `div` matching `.<lastClassName>-wrapper`. This depends on the second class name always being the target `-wrapper` you want to find, but there's no need for any `goDeeper` variable or `level#`-like classes:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  const selector = `.${$(this)[0].classList[1]}-wrapper`;
  $(selector).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.level { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn first">show first div</div>
<div class="level first-wrapper">
  <div class="btn foo">show foo</div>
  <div class="btn bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="level foo-wrapper">
  <div class="btn foo-lma">show lma</div>
  <div class="btn foo-orb">show orb (doesn't exist)</div>
</div>

<div class="level foo-lma-wrapper">
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god, THANK YOU! It is so simple and it works. I am a designer by profession and programming is new to me, still learning.